# how to use jquery ui alert inside if condition

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I am trying to give alert when "if condition" is true, I am using jquery ui alert for that. but the alert wont appear.

here is my code:

```
$("#ctl_apply").on("click", function(event){

       if(from_date > to_date)
       {
            $("#approve_confirm_dialog").dialog({

                height:"auto",
                width:250,
                resizable:false,
                buttons:{

                    "Ok"  : function(){

                            $(this).dialog('close');
                    }   
                }
        });
          return;
       }
});
```

Help?

Comment: create a example link so that we can check and tell the possible solutions

Comment: Is execution  reaching inside the condition..? Because calling alert looks okay..

Answer (score 0):

I think you forget to include the required JS libraries or some thing else. Jquery UI dialog is very simple to use like:

```
$('#alert').dialog();

<div id="alert">
  Alert!!
</div>
```

[Working Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/cubttgow/1/)

Answer (score 0):

If I have to guess, you probably forgot the `docready`. I forget this alllll the time... :)

```
$(function() { //<--- this
  $("#ctl_apply").on("click", function(event){

   if(from_date > to_date)
   {
        $("#approve_confirm_dialog").dialog({

            height:"auto",
            width:250,
            resizable:false,
            buttons:{

                "Ok"  : function(){

                        $(this).dialog('close');
                }   
            }
    });
      return;
   }
  });
}); //<-- and this
```